# Lua/Torch model build, unclear nn.SplitTable

Tags: deep-learning, lua, torch

**Can someone explain what this line does?**

seq = nn.Sequential()

seq:add(nn.SplitTable(d+1, 3))  -- This one knowing that d = 1 or 2